# Using collection action in Active admin for selected objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am implementing an admin panel with Active Admin for my rails application.

I have a comment section inside admin panel, and I'd like to approve a group of comments by checking the comments I'd like to approve and then clicking update button.

In my previous version of admin panel part of page that did group updating looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "admin/comments", :action => "update_statuses") do %>
   <table>
   <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag("comments[]", comment.id) %></td>
          #More table cells with info about comment
          </tr>
   <%end%>
</table>
<%= select_tag "status", options_for_select(comment_statuses) %>
<%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

How to get similar functionality in active admin?

Answer (score 2):

Right now active admin is missing such a feature. If you want to go for alternate rails admin interface then [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is much better for such kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Batch functionality is currently being worked on and introduced in the master branch of ActiveAdmin. Heres how it looks.

http://dribbble.com/shots/265461-Active-Admin-Batch-edit-popover